# How to plot sine wave in Python with sudden amplitude change?

Tags: python, trigonometry, fault

Posted: 7/4/2020

I was wondering if anyone knows how to plot a sine wave with let's say amplitude of 0.1 as a start and then continuing on as usual. Until at one point, the amplitude change to 1.0. Like a sudden surge of change in amplitude. It's like I was an oscillatory system that was stable, and becoming unstable at one point. The plot that I am expecting is as follow:

[image: fault current model]

Regards,
Anis

Updated progress: 18/4/2020

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plotter
from scipy import signal
# How many time points are needed i,e., Sampling Frequency
samplingFrequency   = 1500
# At what intervals time points are sampled
samplingInterval       = 1 / samplingFrequency;
# Begin time period of the signals
beginTime           = 0;
# End time period of the signals
endTime             = 0.3;
# Frequency of the signals
signal1Frequency     = 50;
#Time points
time  = np.arange(beginTime, endTime, samplingInterval);
phase = 180
pi = np.pi
phi = phase*pi/180
# Create two waves- sine and square
amplitude1 = np.sin(2*np.pi*signal1Frequency*time)

amplitude2 = signal.square(2 * np.pi * 50 * time+ phi )
figure, axis = plotter.subplots(1, 1)
plotter.subplots_adjust(hspace=1)


if (time >0.2):
    amplitude = 3*amplitude1
    plotter.plot(time, amplitude)
    plotter.title('test')
    plotter.show()
```

Above is the code that I am currently working on. It keeps on popping an error to due to ambiguity. Requesting me to use a.all() and a.any() function to solve it. When I did do so, I am not getting the surge point that I am expecting. So any ideas on it? I am using time as x axis instead of indexing. And I am using numoy sine instead of math library. This is because when I tried FFT for code proposed below, I am not getting a 50 Hz, it was more of 30 or 10 Hz, and that is understandable given that the frequency was not set and it depends on the periodic cycle created by the sinusoid itself.

Regards,
Anis

Comment: The question seems too vague. Please provide what have you tried already.

Comment: Have a look at matplotlib ...

Comment: @Ardweaden so far I only know to plot a simple sine wave and changing its characteristics (the usual way, amplitude, phase, cycle, frequency, etc), so now I am just stuck on figuring out how to write the program to model that kind of sine wave.

Comment: It's more a math or [DSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signal_processing) question to me. The way you implement the math then, can be asked here, but if you don't even have the math behind what you want to do, we can't do much. Do you have signal data? Do you want to simulate some phenomena? If so, do you know the equation(s) that describe it?

Comment: I read your comment about modelling the sine. I have updated my answer with a simple example.

Comment: @s.k I apologized that I am too straight forward in asking questions with no proposed ideas at all. Thank you for the advice, I will take note next time when I ask a question. I was too blank on how to do it, got some ideas but I am not sure how to put in words so people would understand. Plus, I am quite new with Python. So, I thought of asking if anyone has any idea about it, that can help me out.

Comment: @s.k To answer your question:Yes, I do have signal data, but as for now, I am trying to make things simple by working with Python generated signal first. Also no, I do not know any equations that describe it. I did try doing some research on it but no fixed or pre-defined function available to model a fault current signal, maybe because it can take many forms. I am just trying figure out modelling a simple fault signal (sine wave with amplitude surge)

Comment: I have looked into it some more. Your time variable is a list. So you should loop through it with 'for t in time:'. Inside the loop calculate amplitude for each t and place it in x and y lists. When done plot it.

Comment: I have adjusted my code to period time.See my last answer. For me that was easier than then using np. I hope it helps. If so then please accept the answer to give credit.

Comment: @Mace Thank you very much. It would be ofc my pleasure to accept it and give credits to you. How can I do that? You patiently helped me out a lot. I will also put a citation in my report as well since I referred a lot on sample codes you made to give me ideas on how to do it.

Comment: Just click the V mark left to my answer. Thanks for your compliments. Nice to hear. I hope you will het nice FFTs. A small tip: increasing the sampling frequency 2x or 3x will get more detailed results and thus better FFTs. Have fun!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have converted the code to period time:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
# uses the list amplitude_changes to get the amplitude for time t
def get_amplitude(t):
    for amplitude_change in amplitude_changes:
        if t >= amplitude_change['t']:
            amplitude = amplitude_change['amplitude']

    return amplitude


# --------------------------------------------------------------------------
def y_func(time, period_time, amplitude):
    return amplitude * math.sin((time / period_time) * 2 * math.pi)

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------


t_values = []
amplitude_values = []

signal1Frequency = 50
period_time = 1 / signal1Frequency
sampling_frequency = 1500

delta_t = 1 / sampling_frequency


amplitude_changes = [
                        {'t': 0, 'amplitude': 1},
                        {'t': period_time * 0.9, 'amplitude': 1.5},
                        {'t': period_time * 0.95, 'amplitude': 1},
                        {'t': period_time * 1.2, 'amplitude': 0.8},
                        {'t': period_time * 1.25, 'amplitude': 1},
                    ]

max_t = period_time * 3                     # plot 3 periods
t = 0
while t <= max_t:
    t_values.append(t)
    amplitude = get_amplitude(t)
    amplitude_values.append(y_func(t, period_time, amplitude))
    t += delta_t


plt.plot(t_values, amplitude_values)
plt.title(f'f = {signal1Frequency} Hz (T = {period_time}) - Sampling frequency = {sampling_frequency} Hz')
plt.show()
```

Result

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could plot a piece-wise `sin` function where the second part defines the surge happening and you can change the amplitude there.

For instance:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

surge_point = 50
amplitudeAfterSurge = 4
T = 50
x_normal = np.linspace(0, surge_point, 1000)
x_surge = np.linspace(surge_point, 150, 1000)

y_normal = [math.sin(2*math.pi*i/T) for i in x_normal] # first part of the function

# second part ,note `amplitudeAfterSurge` multiplying the function
y_surge = [amplitudeAfterSurge * math.sin(2*math.pi*i/T) for i in x_surge] 

plt.plot(x_normal, y_normal , 'r')
plt.plot(x_surge, y_surge , 'r')

plt.show()
```

And you will get:

[image: piecewisesinfunction]

Comment: This is awesome! This was what I had in mind to do ie multiple functions that work chain-like. But does this mean that the point of surge (for the abrupt change in amplitude) only works at zero crossings?  Also, thank you so much for your help and idea. Really appreciate it:)

Answer (score 1):

Just like a sine wave in reality if the amplitude changes. You connect the dots of the amplitude just before and just after the change. It's not different from plotting the sine wave itself. How it looks, sharps edges for example, depends only of the moment the change happens.

This is a very basic way of calculating the points and plotting the lines between them.

At x=5 I double the amplitude.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

def y_func(x):
    return math.sin(x)

x_values = []
y_values = []

x = 0

amplitude = 1
while x < 5:
    x_values.append(x)
    y_values.append(amplitude * y_func(x))
    x += 0.1

amplitude = 2
while x < 10:
    x_values.append(x)
    y_values.append(amplitude * y_func(x))
    x += 0.1

plt.plot(x_values, y_values)

plt.title('test')
plt.show()
```

[image]

After structuring it some more and putting the desired amplitude changes in a list, it's easy to produces nice spikes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
def get_amplitude(x):
    for amplitude_change in amplitude_changes:
        if x >= amplitude_change['x']:
            amplitude = amplitude_change['amplitude']

    return amplitude


# --------------------------------------------------------------------------
def y_func(x, amplitude):
    return amplitude * math.sin(x)

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------

amplitude_changes = [
                        {'x': -1, 'amplitude': 1},
                        {'x': 6.5, 'amplitude': 2.2},
                        {'x': 6.7, 'amplitude': 1},
                        {'x': 9.1, 'amplitude': 0.5},
                        {'x': 9.2, 'amplitude': 1.2},
                        {'x': 9.4, 'amplitude': 1},
                    ]

x_values = []
y_values = []

x = 0
max_x = 10
step = 0.1

while x <= max_x:
    x_values.append(x)
    amplitude = get_amplitude(x)
    y_values.append(y_func(x, amplitude))
    x += step

plt.plot(x_values, y_values)
plt.title('test')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah you are on the right track and that is what I am trying to do but I am not entirely sure how or when I can insert those 'dots'. But I'll keep looking though. I have not yet had any idea on code for this since its quite mind-boggling for me to figure this out. Please feel free to shout ideas, small steps would be fine too.

Comment: This is so coool. Very interesting! I will give it a shot. I am excited to see what the FFT looks like for this one. Actually, I have asked this question in another post (but I guess it was too power system-ish) that I have got no replies at all about it. Thank you so much for your idea and help! Really appreciate it:)

Comment: Here is the link to it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61014943/13089196

Comment: Glad I can help. I have put some structure in the program that makes it easier to put some nice artifacts in your wave and produce a lot of spikes in the FFT's. :-))

Comment: I have edited my question by adding a code that I working on. Instead of using x-axis (defined by range of numbers). I am trying to use time as the x-axis. And the sine wave that I use now is a 50 Hz one. Before this, with the python math module, I do not know how to define its frequency so hence why I opted for NumPy.

Comment: It's all about converting period time to radials. But that's a bit beyond the topic of the original question. I think it's better to post a new question. If so I will try to answer with some code about it. Give a comment here when posted so I can look into it.

Comment: I see though I don't really understand what does it mean by conversion. I'll read more about it. Thank you very much again. I will take note on making a new question out of this. Once I posted it, I will let you know here. I have one more question though, why is it using math module is much easier than NumPy?