# plot analog wave from 9 points of freq and power in python

Tags: python-3.x

Good day Everyone, I'm new there  hope someone will guide me and help me with my query.

is there away to plot the wave of signal using python? i have 9 points of frequency an power and i want it plot it using python v3.6.

i found some recourse like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61081943/how-to-plot-sine-wave-in-python-with-sudden-amplitude-change) and [here](https://pythontic.com/visualization/charts/sinewave) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566692/python-how-to-plot-graph-sine-wave/34442729) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566692/python-how-to-plot-graph-sine-wave) i have try the code in below , but i want the graph shows as wave not in same that way. any suggest ?

code is :

```
    # importing the required module 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
  
# x axis values 
x = [54,58,61,62,64,65,66,69,72] # frequency
# corresponding y axis values 
y = [2,2.5,4,3,2.5,3.5,4.5,3,2]   # Power
  
# plotting the points  
plt.plot(x, y) 
  
# naming the x axis 
plt.xlabel('x - axis') 
# naming the y axis 
plt.ylabel('y - axis') 
  
# giving a title to my graph 
plt.title('My first graph!') 
  
# function to show the plot 
plt.show()
```

code of sin-wave, how i modify the code in below to assign the value of frequency and power as :  freq = [54,58,61,62,64,65,66,69,72] # frequency and Power = [2,2.5,4,3,2.5,3.5,4.5,3,2]   # Power

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TKAgg') #use matplotlib backend TkAgg (optional)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sample_rate = 200 # sampling frequency in Hz (atleast 2 times f)
t = np.linspace(0,5,sample_rate)    #time axis
f = 100 #Signal frequency in Hz
sig = np.sin(2*np.pi*f*(t/sample_rate))
plt.plot(t,sig)
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("Amplitude")
plt.tight_layout() 
plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you. Also, take some time to review the previous posts you cited, before you give up

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python how to plot graph sine wave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566692/python-how-to-plot-graph-sine-wave)

Comment: thank you for reply, i have modify the code by attach the sign-wave, but how i make the wave of 9 points of frequency and power?

Comment: Can you more fully explain what you mean by the 9 points of frequency?  Frequency is usually expressed in terms of cycles/unit of time.  Do you mean you have 9 different frequencies?  Also, what do you mean by power?  Are you equating power with amplitude?  Finally, what is meant by the statement "but i want the graph shows as wave